# equal value = equal rank

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to rank the elements of a list such that elements that have the same value also get the same rank:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5}
```

desired output:

```
ranks = {5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1}
```

`Ordering[]` does almost what I want but assigns different ranks to the two instances of `4` in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I cover everything you have in mind, but the following code will give the desired output. It presupposes that the smallest value is the highest rank, and should work with numerical values or as long as you are ok with the standard sorting order of Mathematica.  The local variable dv is a shortname for "distinct values".

```
  FromListToRanks[k_List]:= Module[ {dv=Reverse[Union[k]]},
    k /. Thread[dv -> Range[Length[dv]]] ]


  FromListToRanks[list]

  {5,4,3,2,2,1}
```